# CONCATENATION, smallint, integer into an integer column

Tags: db2, concatenation, mainframe

DB2 V9 z/os

Background: I have a 4 column table defined as `(col1 int, col2 smallint, col3 int, col4 date)`

Row 1 has values of (1,123,456,2012-08-23)

When I execute the following:

```
SELECT CAST(col2 AS VARCHAR(5)) CONCAT CAST(col3 AS VARCHAR(5))
  FROM db.T1 
 WHERE col1 = 1;
```

Value 123456 is returned, which is exactly what i want.

When I execute the following:

```
UPDATE db.table2
   SET col3 = SELECT CAST(col2 AS VARCHAR(5)) CONCAT CAST(col3 AS VARCHAR(5))
  FROM db.T1 
 WHERE col1 = 1;
```

Error is:

> SQL0408N  A value is not compatible with the data type of its assignment target.  Target name is "col3".  SQLSTATE=42821

I understand the error is due to attempting to insert a varchar into an integer. What else can I do? I've tried using various CAST statements but cannot get a value to insert into col3. i need the value to appear joined as shown above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You really should add relevant tags when asking questions to increase the visibility of your question.  There's no way anyone would have known this was a DB2 question based off the tags or title.

Comment: I have to ask, why are you doing this?

Comment: I have to update column A by concatenating the values of columns B & A.

Comment: Nothing to add other than point out my love for LittleBobbyTables's user name, and hope that s/he sanitizes her/his inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping all of the casts as a final `cast( ... as integer)` should work:

```
UPDATE db.table2 
SET col3 = SELECT CAST(
        CAST(col2 AS VARCHAR(5)) CONCAT CAST(col3 AS VARCHAR(5)) 
    AS INTEGER)
FROM db.T1 
WHERE col1 = 1;
```

Comment: @JohnMilton - Glad that worked.  If you check the checkbox next to the answer, other users will know the question has been answered.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to the website and still figuring out things out.

Answer (score 0):

depend on the MAXIMUM value of your small integers,
you can convert them to base-9,
then concatenate with '9'.

```
CONCAT( IFNULL(CONV(sint1, 10, 9),''), 
        '9', 
        IFNULL(CONV(tint2, 10, 9),'')
      ) AS combined
```

and another option, ALSO depend on the MAXIMUM value of your small integers,
to PAD-LEFT with zeros one of them.

```
CONCAT(
         sint1, 
         LPAD(tint2,3,0)
) AS combined
```

See full code and explanation: https://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2021/10/mysql-joincombine-2-smallinttinyint.html